# How to avoid librarian attacks reliably?

Tags: metro-2033, metro-2033-redux

I am trying to pass through the library by killing the librarians, instead of staring them down.

However I can't seem to be able to avoid their attacks (3 of which will kill you) reliably.

Is there a particular strategy to prevent librarian from reaching and hitting you?

Comment: I'd recommend being a little quieter in the library to avoid librarian attacks.

Comment: SaintWacko is right, I don't know if you're meant to kill them. If you're really hardcore, you could probably do it, but I don't think you're meant to.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf if I remember correctly, you can kill them, but it *really* isn't worth it nor is it easy. Big waste of ammo.

Comment: To clarify: I know you can kill them. I also know you can avoid them by sneaking or stare them down. But I want to kill them and I'm looking for a strategy to avoid their melee attacks.

Answer (score 1):

From research and YouTube videos, looks like using the Helsing is a way to "avoid" his melee attacks by killing them before they reach you.

Overpressurized, it takes about 5 arrows to kill one.